# If server 2008 system will be formatted, how to get all users information (Usernames and passowrds)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, workgroup

If I have to reformat a Server 2008 system, how do I get all the users information (usernames and passwords) copied to the rebuilt system?

Answer (score 3):

User's Information: Backup it up with wbadmin at an elevated command prompt or just copy / paste it to another source.

Usernames: If it's in a domain, open ADUC, create a query for usernames and export the information to a text file. If it's in a workgroup, open the Local Users and Groups MMC, right lick the "Users" folder and select "Export list"

User's Passwords: From a practical standpoint, you can't... unless you want to try to [crack the NTLM hashes](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: And this is why we use Active Directory for user password management.

Comment: Does pwdump still work with Server 2008? If so that would be my tool of choice for the password problem.